# Jupiter seems to break multimonitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, jupiter

If Jupiter is in the startup my multimonitor setup will fail. Instead of two separate desktops the monitors will be mirrored, one over the other with the smaller notebook-desktop in the larger screen:
[image]

After each new log-in I have to reset the Display settings in the "System Settings..." dialogue to two not mirrored screens, the changes don't seem to be saved.

Given the the entry from xsession-errors

```
/usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/resolutions: line 42: /var/jupiter/available_resolutions_LVDS: Permission denied
```

I assumed that it's coming from Jupiter. Infact, if Jupiter is removed as startup application the desktop settings are fine.

Any idea how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it, *but* I do not remember which solution works.

Firstly try changing Jupiter settings:

> **Jupiter → Video Displays → Both Displays** (internal left)

*I have a laptop on the left, but maybe for you it should be (internal right) and restart.*

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
unity --reset
```

but after that, you have to set your Compiz settings one more time.